# How to solve/factor polynomials with coefficients that are dot products?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to solve the following equation:

$$ 
4\left(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}\right)t^3+6\left(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{v}\right)t^2+\left(2\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}+4\vec{a}\cdot\vec{s}\right)t+2\left(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{s}\right)  = 0
$$

for $t$, where $\vec{a}, \vec{v}, \vec{s}$ are known vectors. I managed to obtain the following factorization:

$$
\left(2\vec{a}t^2+2\vec{v}t+2\vec{s}\right)\left(2\vec{a}t+\vec{v}\right) = 0
$$

However, I run into a problem when actually finding $t$ using this factorization. For instance, one solution would be where the second factor is $0$:

$$ t = \frac{-\vec{v}}{2\vec{a}} $$

But how would you divide two vectors? I have a similar problem when using the quadratic formula with the first factor. The factorization seems correct to me but clearly I am doing something wrong. Is there a way to factor the equation while preserving dot products or perhaps another method to resolve my issue? Thanks!

Also, for context, I am trying to solve the Closest Point of Approach problem with two bodies moving with constant acceleration rather than constant velocity, which is what most resources I have found assume. I can use a solver to find the necessary $t$ values but an analytical solution would be great for computational purposes.

I found a similar question asked here before but it does not look like anyone found an analytical solution. It's an old question and I am not sure how to contact the author to see if he found a solution. Here's a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244432/collision-detection-between-two-accelerating-spheres-with-no-initial-velocity

Comment: Are your vectors $\vec{a},\vec{v},\vec{s}$ coplanar ?

Comment: Pay attention, a dot product $\vec{U} \cdot \vec{V}$ is zero if either $\vec{U}=0$ or $\vec{V}=0$ (particular cases) $ \ \color{red}{O}\color{red}{R}: \ \ \vec{U} \perp \vec{V}$, the latter being the general case.

Comment: IMHO, unfortunately, your factorization does not provide a way to have an analytical solution better than to look directly for an analytical solution using Cardano's formulas for a third degree equation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clarification of your **find-a-root** problem, transforming it into a **minimization problem** that can be tackled with different, efficient tools (though not with analytical formulas), explaining what you call the (equivalent) "Closest point approach".

First of all, let it be clear that a dot product $\vec{U} \cdot \vec{V}$ is zero if

- either $\vec{U}=0$ or $\vec{V}=0$
- $\color{red}{O}\color{red}{R}: \ \ \vec{U} \perp \vec{V}$,

the latter being the general case.

Your equation deserves to be written in the following way :

$$\tag{1}2 \underbrace{\left(\vec{a}t^2+\vec{v}t+\vec{s}\right)}_{\vec{P(t)}}  
 \cdot \underbrace{\left(2\vec{a}t+\vec{v}\right)}_{\vec{P'(t)}} = 0$$

where $\vec{P'(t)}$ is plainly the derivative of $\vec{P(t)}$ with respect to $t$.

But in  (1), i.e., in $2 \vec{P(t)} \cdot  \vec {P'(t)}=0$ we recognize the following differentiation :

$$\tag{2} \tfrac{d}{dt}\vec{\|P(t)\|^2} = 0$$

Thus (2), which expresses that a certain derivative is zero, is equivalent to find an extremum of function $\vec{\|P(t)\|^2}$ (in fact a minimum due to the convexity of the issue)

This function (of $t$) describes a curve, which is in fact a parabola (nothing surprizing for a move with constant acceleration!).

Thus our issue is to find the point of this curve that is closest to the origin.

If we assume that vectors $\vec{a},\vec{v},\vec{s}$ are coplanar, all the information is gathered in the figure below.

Consider the cyan circle as the limit position of a circle centered at the origin that has been inflated till it comes in contact with the parabola. The contact point corresponds to a particular value $t_0$ of $t$. The directing vector of the common tangent to the parabola and to the limit circle at this point is represented with a magenta color;  in particular, it is orthogonal to the corresponding radius of the circle (the other magenta vector).

**Edit :** Why is parametric curve

$$\tag{3}\vec{P(t)}:=\vec{s}+t\vec{v}+t^2\vec{a}$$

a parabola ? Here is an explanation. First, let us define a new axes' origin $\Omega$ by setting $\vec{s}=\vec{0\Omega}$. It means that with respect to this new origin, (3) can be written $\vec{\tilde P(t)}=t\vec{v}+t^2\vec{a}$. Now, with this new origin $\Omega$, taking "slant axes" defined by $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{a}$ one gets equation $y=x^2$, the simplest possible equation for a parabola.

[image]

Comment: You haven't answered my question about coplanarity of vectors $\vec{a},\vec{v},\vec{s}$. Besides, could you say if you have understood my solution or if some points are obscure ? (I have added some explanations at the end). Think that Math SE is done for promoting interactions between people.

Comment: Apologize for not responding earlier and thank you for the answer! Yes they are coplanar. The geometric intuition is great and something I did not see at all. But I mainly wish to find an analytic solution as I will be using a computer program to solve this equation for hundreds of vectors

Comment: For a computer, an iterative solution is a good alternative.